# Get input field value and display it in a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display input field value in a div after submitting the form.But I am unable to do it.
What I am doing wrong?.
can somebody help me?

```js
function validate() {
      var a = document.forms["Form"]["uname"].value;
      var validation=true;

      if ((a == null || a == "")||(!a.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/))) {
        document.getElementById('uname').className = 'box';
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML=  document.getElementById('uname').value;
        validation=false;
      } else{
        document.getElementById('uname').className = '';
      }

      return validation;
}
```

```css
.box {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#popup {
    width:25%;
    height:115px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:2% ;
    margin-left: 60%;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return validate()" action="" id="form_id">
      <label>NAME:</label>
      <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="fields" >
      <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      <div id="popup"></div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://output.jsbin.com/fujacuh

Comment: Code works just fine. I don't see any problem with it either.

Comment: that is a weird form - it posts if it fails validation but doesn't if it passes?

Comment: @MoshFeu I can validate it. But I am unable to display input value in a div.

Comment: Again, works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B3Uw.png

Comment: Then why its not works for me?

Comment: Do you mean in your code? Or in the attached snippet? Because the snippet is in `savndbox` iframe so it disallow `form` submitting.

Comment: @MoshFeu I am not saying about snippet. My code is not working when i click submit after entering input filed,It should display some data in div right?But I am getting nothing.

Comment: OK. I just need to see the problem a live so I could debug it. I need to understand what is the difference between your code and my. Can you create a snippet the reproduce the problem? Or do you have a public url of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is if else condition. Inner html should be in else condition

```
 if ((a == null || a == "")||(!a.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/))) {
        document.getElementById('uname').className = 'box';
        validation=false;
      } else{
        document.getElementById('uname').className = '';
        document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML=  document.getElementById('uname').value;
      }
```